# NetBeans 6.8 doesn't detect installed Rails on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans6.8

I  use Netbeans 6.8 with Ror. If  i click "AutoDetect Platforms" , IDE detect Ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i486-linux], but when i try to create RoR project, it says that Ror not detected.What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby != RoR.

Are you sure you have Rails installed on the machine?  If not, try running `gem update rails` and making sure you have it installed.